# CSS font not working

Tags: html, css

The font in the form labels on this page - http://bakebox.in/order-form/ must be the same as in this page -  http://bakebox.in/test/
I have tried to use the same font tag for both, but it does not work

```
font: 300 18px 'BebasNeueRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
```

Comment: -1 posting nothing but links that will become useless after you fix your issue.  [Please read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: You can use Firebug to see the 'Computed' CSS on any element.

Comment: The part where it is not working is inside an `iframe`, so basically that is [another page](http://bakebox.in/website-order-form.html).

Comment: @ACJ Bingo! Best I can tell the `@font-face` declaration is missing from the iframe document. @progit see my answer below.

Comment: @KevinBoucher, I re-worded my comment.  One major point of SO is to be a repository of helpful Q & A for future readers.  No matter how you look at it, this question will be of little use to future readers as it's currently written.  Posting only an expiring link and saying _"no worky, solve it"_ is a selfish way to use this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be missing the `@font-face` declaration that is in the working version:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "BebasNeueRegular";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("BebasNeue/BebasNeue-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("BebasNeue/BebasNeue-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("BebasNeue/BebasNeue-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("BebasNeue/BebasNeue-webfont.svg#BebasNeueRegular") format("svg");
}
```

In the wp-content/themes/in-motion/style.css stylesheet.

Comment: Already checked, the css file is included in both pages

Comment: @xception: It is not. Check http://bakebox.in/website-order-form.html.

Comment: @ACJ it was when I viewed it's source originally, guess he's working on it at the moment, I hate it when they give you a sample of the live server they're currently modifying.